# Why can't I resize my button width and place them side by side in @media

Tags: css

I have two buttons on the home page.

The correct selector is

```
.btn
```

I want just these two side by side and smaller for mobile view.

Tried:

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .btn {
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 10px; 
        width: 10px;
    }
}
```

The height changed, nothing else did, the buttons remained on top of each other in the same place.

Tried:

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .btn {
        display: block; 
        float: left; 
        height: 10px; 
        width: 10px;
    }
}
```

The button height went down to half, the width stayed the same and, instead of going side by side, stayed on top of each other.

Tried the same code with:

```
@media screen and
```

Nothing

Live URL: https://adsler.co.uk/

Comment: You are not so clear, but try: `float: right`

Comment: Edited question. Better?

Comment: {display: block; float: right;}?

Comment: Can you provide some part of your html code with buttons? Generally, the not styled buttons place on the same line.

Comment: Please show us what's going on with: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: <div class="top-parallax-section">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
         <div class="mb32"></div><a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-place-ad/">Post</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/">Search</a>        </div>
       </div>
       <!--

Answer (score 0):

Updated the question with the live URL.

This should be what you want.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .btn { 
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 28px; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        width: 151px; 
        min-width: 80px; 
        padding: 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188552/discussion-on-answer-by-jennifer-goncalves-why-cant-i-resize-my-button-width-an). If the answers do not work for you, please ensure that you have provided an adequate [mcve] in the question.

Comment: But it's better to view in mobile, then you can see what i mean